# Writing a nested for loop in Ruby

Tags: python, arrays, ruby

I have an array `slots`, which is comprised of other arrays of timeslots (e.g. `["9:30 AM", "10:00 AM"]` (except as actual time objects). I'm trying to iterate over them with a nested for loop.

Here's the Python version of what I'm trying to do:

```
for start, end in ((slots[i][1], slots[i + 1][0]) for i in range(len(slots) - 1)):
   ...
```

How would I write this in Ruby?

Edit:

What I'm trying to do is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702224/python-algorithm-find-time-slots) in Ruby. I want to implement the accepted solution in that link in Ruby.

Comment: Would `for (_, start), (end,_) in zip(slots, slots[1:]):` be equivalent to your code? (just curious, I don't know Python)

Comment: Please, complete the `slots` list: it's unclear how actually is.

Comment: BTW, you might want to give a more complete example along with the expected output. From your code alone it's not obvious what you are trying to do.

Comment: @express_v2 : Maybe you could populate your example `slots` with several elements and then show which values should be processed in each iteration. Your question is unclear to me; in particular, I can not see from it, whether the answer given by Stefan or given by Dmitry would solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```rb
slots.each { |s, e| ... }
```

If you want to omit the last slot:

```rb
slots[1..-1].each { |s, e| ... }
```

If you want to get index `i` in loop body:

```rb
slots[1..-1].each.with_index { |s, e, i| ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a nested array like this:

```
slots = [
  ['9:30 AM', '10:00 AM'],
  ['10:30 AM', '11:00 AM'],
  ['11:30 AM', '12:00 PM']
]
```

If you want to get the last and first value of consecutive elements – i.e. the end of the one slot and the beginning of the next – you can use [`each_cons`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Enumerable.html#each_cons-method) to get neighboring pairs:

```
slots.each_cons(2) do |slot_a, slot_b|
  p ends: slot_a[1], starts: slot_b[0]
end
```

You can also use [array decomposition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) to assign the array elements to variables: (the `_` denotes an unused variable)

```
slots.each_cons(2) do |(_, ends), (starts, _)|
  p ends: ends, starts: starts
end
```

Output:

```
{:ends=>"10:00 AM", :starts=>"10:30 AM"}
{:ends=>"11:00 AM", :starts=>"11:30 AM"}
```

Note that I've called the end of the first slot `ends` and the beginning of the next slot `starts`. If you want to have it the other way round like in your example, just flip the variables.